# MySQL Select where multiple rows in joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, inner-join, having

Let's say I have two tables, something like:

```
+-----------------------------+
|a                            |
+------+-----------+----------+
| a_id | firstname | lastname |
+------+-----------+----------+
|    1 | Tom       | Cruise   |
|    3 | Matt      | Damon    |
|    4 | Ben       | Affleck  |
|    8 | Ryan      | Gosling  |
+------+-----------+----------+

+-----------------------+
| b                     |
+------+------+---------+
| b_id | a_id | b_value |
+------+------+---------+
|    2 |    3 | one     |
|    1 |    3 | two     |
|    4 |    8 | three   |
|    8 |    1 | four    |
+------+------+---------+
```

I would like to be able to`SELECT` rows from `a` which meet a set of criteria from `b`, where there might be multiple rows.

For example:

- Get the first and last name(s) of anyone who has a `b_value` of one, and other `b_value` of two. In the example data, this refers only to Matt Damon.
- Get the first and last name(s) of anyone who has a `b_value` of three, or a `b_value` of four. In the example data, Ryan Gosling has a `b_value` of three, and Tom Cruise has a `b_value` of four, so both Ryan Gosling and Tom Cruise would be returned.
- Get the first and last name(s) of anyone that has either:

  - A `b_value` of one and another `b_value` of two.
  - A `b_value` of three.

In the example data, Matt Damon meets the first condition, and Ryan Gosling meets the second condition, so both are returned.

The difficulty comes from when these conditions are complex, combining multiple and/or conditions, and a variable in length.

My current attempt (solving specifically example 3 in this case), is using aggregate functions in the `HAVING`:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname 
FROM temp_a INNER JOIN temp_b ON temp_a.a_id = temp_b.a_id 
GROUP BY temp_a.a_id 
HAVING (SUM(b_value="one") AND SUM(b_value="two")) OR SUM(b_value="three");
```

Which gets the correct rows, but there's two immediate problems with this approach for me:

- `SUM` seems wrong and complicated. I'd have to find each of the conditionals and make sure each one is wrapped in a `SUM`, of which there might be lots.
- The `b_value` is indexed, and `b` has lots of rows. The `HAVING` clause doesn't use the index and so the query is noticeably slow.

Is there a different approach I should be taking to do this sort of query, bearing in mind I'm not really in direct control of the conditionals used for filtering.

Comment: Could you please add what the final result should be. It's not clear. Also in your second example you say where b_value is three OR four and it should return Ryan Gosling AND Tom Cruise. If you specify OR in the first part you can't have AND in the second part, I guess, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Kevin I've updated the question a bit, hopefully that clarifies things

Comment: In your example you have specified 3 examples, I guess there will be other posibilities to filter on? I would almost suggest using dynamic sql. I also guess the filters are made by a user? Maybe you can prepare your where clause in the application, pass it a variable and place it in your dynamic sql statement to execute.

Comment: @Kevin Yeah that's right. Sorry, I thought that was implied - my bad. How would that dynamic sql statement look?

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists a,b;
create table a( a_id int, firstname varchar(20), lastname varchar(20));
insert into a values
(    1 , 'Tom'       , 'Cruise' ),  
(    3 , 'Matt'      , 'Damon'  ),  
(    3 , 'Ben'       , 'Affleck'),  
(    8 , 'Ryan'      , 'Gosling');  

create table b( b_id int, a_id int, b_value varchar(20));
insert into b values
(    2 ,    3 , 'one'  ),   
(    1 ,    3 , 'two'  ),   
(    4 ,    8 , 'three'),   
(    8 ,    1 , 'four' );


select firstname, lastname,s.vals
from a
join
(
select b.a_id, group_concat(b_value) vals from b group by b.a_id
) s on a.a_id = s.a_id

where s.vals in ('one,two') or s.vals in ('three')

+-----------+----------+---------+
| firstname | lastname | vals    |
+-----------+----------+---------+
| Matt      | Damon    | one,two |
| Ben       | Affleck  | one,two |
| Ryan      | Gosling  | three   |
+-----------+----------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: While `s.vals in ('one,two')` works for the example query and data given, it won't work for other queries. I imagine the database will contain a situation where s.val is 'a,b,c' and the filter is 'a,c'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rows from a where it has b_value of both one and two would return Matt Damon.
```

if you want above result then table "a" "id" column should have unique records,
table a and b both should have primary key.

or you can try following query, but it will return double records for "matt daemon"

```
select firstname,lastname from a left join b on a.a_id=b.a_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In dynamic SQL it would somthing like this, first I would suggest creating a variable in your application which you fill up based on the selection of filters

```
 - var exampleOne = "(b_value = 'one') OR (b_value = 'two')";
 - var exampleTwo = "(b_value = 'three') OR (b_value = 'four')";
 - var exampleThree = "(b_value = 'one' or b_value = 'two') OR (b_value = 'three')"
```

Then you can create a stored procedure with one parameter, here you pass in your variable

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `spNames`(IN whereFilter VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  SET @SqlText = CONCAT('SELECT DISTINCT a.firstname, a.lastname 
                         FROM @a AS a INNER JOIN @b AS b ON a.a_id=b.a_id
                         WHERE ', whereFilter);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @SqlText;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt
END
```

Then you can call this stored procedure from your code and pass in the variable

```
CALL spNames (exampleOne);
```

Comment: Example three here is unfortunately not quite right. If there were another row in b, say with values `(3, 1, "one")`, then Tom Cruise would get incorrectly returned because there is a `b_value` of one, but there is no `b_value` of two - but in the variable the `(b_value = 'one' or b_value = 'two')` component would be satisfied.